# UIPickerview filter list from a user previous textfield input

Tags: iphone, ios

```
int variabla;

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {


if (variabla == 1)
    return list4.count;

else if(variabla == 2)
    return list3.count;

if (variabla == 3)
    return list1.count;

if (variabla == 4)
    return list2.count;

return YES;

[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if (variabla == 1) {
    subjectField.text = [list4 objectAtIndex:row];
}
else if  (variabla == 2) {
    gradeField.text = [list3 objectAtIndex:row];
}
else if (variabla == 3) {
    mathField.text = [list1 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    coreTView.text = [mathMeaning objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
}
if (variabla == 4) {
    elaField.text = [list2 objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    selectedRow = [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    coreTView.text = [elaMeaning objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
}


[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
NSLog(@"row selected is %d", selectedRow);

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component  {

if (variabla == 1)
    return [list4 objectAtIndex:row];


if (variabla == 2)
    return [list3 objectAtIndex:row];

if (variabla == 3)
    return [list1 objectAtIndex:row];

if (variabla == 4)
    return [list2 objectAtIndex:row];

return NO;

[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

I would like to know or pointed in the right direction on how to load a `UIPickerView` based on the user input from a previous `UITextField` so if they type in the previous textfield **apple**, I would like red, green, blue to show in the `UIPickerView` or if they type **orange**, I would like to see orange, yellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good time to use a multidimensional array:

```
NSArray *titles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
 [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red",@"Green",@"Blue",nil],
 [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Orange",@"Yellow",@"Grape",nil],
 nil];
```

Now all you need is an `int` (looks like you're using `variabla`) that represents the input- for example, if the user entered "Apple", then you'd set `variabla` to 0; if they entered "Orange", set `variabla` to 1; and so on.

Then, you could set up the relevant functions accordingly:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [[titles objectAtIndex:variabla] count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component  {
    return [[titles objectAtIndex:variabla] objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

You may add support for as many words as you want by simply adding another `NSArray` to `titles`.

Answer (score 0):

Just take `BOOL` variable for check that which button user click ,apple or orange...

here take variable like

```
BOOL isApple;
```

when use click on apple button to load pickerview at that time in method set tru this variable like bellow..

```
-(IBAction)btnApple_Clicked(id)sender{
   isApple =TRUE;
   [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}

-(IBAction)btnOrange_Clicked(id)sender{
   isApple =FALSE;
   [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

and then in this delegate method just use like this...

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   if(isApple){
       return [appleArray count];
   }
   else{
       return [orangeArray count];
   }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component  {
    if (isApple) {
        return [appleArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else{
        return [appleArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (isApple) {
        yourTextField.text = [appleArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else{
        yourTextField.text = [appleArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}
```